# Java Print Intitial

Tags: java

I am working on a program and currently have this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

   public static void main(String[] args) {      
      
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
// System.out.print("input :");
       String input = sc.nextLine();
       String[] in = input.split(" ");
// System.out.print("output:");
       if(in.length==3)
           System.out.println(in[2]+" ,"+in[0]+" "+in[1].charAt(0)+".");
       else
           System.out.println(in[1]+", "+in[0]);
   }

}
```

Input:

```
Pat Silly Doe
```

Output:

```
Doe ,Pat S.
```

Expected output:

```
Doe, P.S.
```

I've tried a few different in's and I can't seem to get it.

Comment: what do you get? Have you debugged  your code? I hope you understand why that length isn't 3?

Comment: Please add a proper explanation of the logic for producing the output, we should not have to guess that.

Comment: Have a look at the string you're constructing here: `in[2]+" ,"+in[0]+" "+in[1].charAt(0)+"."` and especially think about what `in[0]` and `in[1]` would be for input `Pat Silly Doe`. Then think about why you get `S.` but not `P.`.

Comment: I mean, really, you've basically done it already, change `in[2]+" ,"+in[0]+" "+in[1].charAt(0)+"."` to `in[2] + ", " + in[0].charAt(0) + "." + in[1].charAt(0) + "."`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(in.length==3) {
    System.out.println(
        in[2]+", "+
        in[0].charAt(0)+"."+
        in[1].charAt(0)+".");
}
```